# Alt+255 in a Batch File

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command, prompt, alt

I'm sure you know of the special Alt+255 character which Windows renders as a blank character.

I am trying to use that Alt+255 character in a batch file, to create a file that contains this special character.

```
copy mybatch.txt "C:\Alt+255My Batch.bat" >nul
```

Result: Alt+255My Batch.bat

So I pasted the actual blank character into the batch file

```
copy mybatch.txt "C:\ My Batch.bat" >nul
```

Result: áMy Batch.bat

So I changed the batch file encoding from ANSI to UTF-8

Result: ┬áMy Batch.bat

Any ideas how I can refer to the blank character inside a batch file?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose the hex/dec value of this symbol should be ff/255.

to create a file that contain this you can use certutil:

```
@echo ff>255.hex
@certutil -decodehex 255.hex 255.bin
```

or you can take a look at [GenChr.bat](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-genchr.html) or [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=23888) or eventually [this](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=1733)